# I found that div scroll event can be fired continuously in Android. But render will lag until scroll ends?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I found that the scroll event is fired continuously in some android devices. But render will lag until scroll ends?

I tested: Samsung Galaxy Nexus

```js
var outerContent = document.getElementById('outer-content');
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var tempStr = '';
var index = 0;

for(var i = 0;i < 800;i++){
  tempStr +='<div class="s-item">\
             <div class="item-bg" style="width:100%;">'+(index++) + '</div>\
             </div>';
}

outerContent.innerHTML = tempStr;

outerContent.onscroll = function(e) {
    //this will update continously during scroll
    document.title = e.target.scrollTop;

    // element change its color only when scroll stop
    demo.style.background = 'yellow';
};
```

```css
.outer-content{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  overflow:auto;
 }

.item-bg{
  height:38px;
  background:green;
 }

#demo{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="outer-content" class="outer-content"></div>
```

Is there some solution for such situation?

Comment: [Demo on jsFiddle to test on a mobile device](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb5LzwhL/)

Comment: This article wraps it up for iOS, basically. I think it might be the same issue with newer Android versions. [Why the Scroll Event Change in iOS 8 is a Big Deal](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/)